# Vaadin LayoutApp not showing component

Tags: vaadin

I created a view in class Teste extending  AppLayout
And in addition I created MainAction that contain Teste as layout
When a run principal/tarefas route it render only a navbar.
how do i render both components

[Code wrote in vaadin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDpr.png)

[Result of Test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNjAW.png)

[Result of Main class having a parent Test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f6NB.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

***Please replace the image links with the actual code. So that we can reference it in our answers and so that others can see the code.***

With that said - I think the issue is that you are calling `AppLayout.setContent(...)` to add your menu. I believe the method you are looking for is `AppLayout.addToDrawer(...)` which will add your menu to the "drawer", which slides in from the left when you click the hamburger/menu icon. Adding it to the drawer means that it will remain on the layout when the "content" changes, which is what happens when you open a new route.